# Is it correct to use DIV inside FORM?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm just wondering what are you thinking about DIV-tag inside FORM-tag?

I need something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div> some </div>
  <div> another </div>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Is it general practice to use `DIV` inside `FORM` or I need something different?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

It is totally fine .

The `form` will submit only its input type controls ( *also `Textarea` , `Select` , etc...).

You have nothing to worry about a `div` within a `form`.

Comment: How about using a form inside a div ?

Comment: @KickButtowski A form inside a div is no problem at all. You can try it yourself at a HTML validator. Besides, it is almost inevitable these days, since the modern pages are build on div's. If it was not allowed, a simple wrapper or placing the form in a container would already make the page invalid.

Comment: Form validation has stopped working for me since I added divs inside the form

Answer (score 34):

**It is completely acceptable to use a DIV inside a `<form>` tag.**

If you look at the default [CSS 2.1 stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), `div` and `p` are both in the `display: block` category.  Then looking at the HTML 4.01 specification for the form element, they include not only `<p>` tags, but `<table>` tags, so of course `<div>` would meet the same criteria.  There is also a `<legend>` tag inside the form in the documentation.

For instance, the following passes HTML4 validation in strict mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test" action="test.php">
<div>
  Test: <input name="blah" value="test" type="text">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use a `<div>` within a form - there is no problem there .... **BUT** if you are going to use the `<div>` as the label for the `input` dont ... `label` is a far better option :

```
<label for="myInput">My Label</label> 
<input type="textbox" name="MyInput" value="" />
```

Answer (score 3):

> Definition and Usage
>
> The  tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.
>
> The  tag is used to group block-elements to format them with
>   styles.
>   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Also [DIV - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/div)

> The HTML  element (or HTML Document Division Element) is the
>   generic container for flow content, which does not inherently
>   represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling
>   purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share
>   attribute values, such as lang. It should be used only when no other
>   semantic element (such as  or ) is appropriate.

You can use div inside form, if you are talking about using div instead of table, then google about Tableless web design

Comment: really? w3schools reference?

Comment: @AdonisK., I know all about why one should not include reference to w3schools, but I believe it doesn't deserve a downvote, I would request you to see this discussion on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link Also I have updated reference of DIV from MDN

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong to have <input> as a direct child of a <form>

And by the way <input **/**> may fail on some doctype

Check it with http://validator.w3.org/check

---

document type does not allow element "INPUT" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "PRE", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag

<input type="text" />

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't address what you want to put in the DIV tags, which is probably why you've received some incomplete/wrong answers.  The truth is that you can, as Royi said, put DIV tags inside of your forms.  You don't want to do this for labels, for instance, but if you have a form with a bunch of checkboxes that you want to lay out into three columns, then by all means, use DIV tags (or SPAN, HEADER, etc.) to accomplish the look and feel you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, it's all good, you can do it just fine.  For me personally, I try to keep a form of hierarchical structure with my elements with a `div` being the outer most parent element.  I try to use only `table` `p` `ul` and `span` inside forms.  Just makes it easier for me to keep track of parent/children relationships inside *my* webpages.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that whenever I would start the form tag inside a div the subsequent div siblings would not be part of the form when I inspect (chrome inspect) henceforth my form would never submit.

```
<div>
<form>
<input name='1st input'/>
</div>
<div>
<input name='2nd input'/>
</div>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

I figured that if I put the form tag outside the DIVs it worked. The form tag should be placed at the start of the parent DIV. Like shown below.

```
<form>
<div>
<input name='1st input'/>
</div>
<div>
<input name='2nd input'/>
</div>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -5):

Absolutely not! It will render, but it will not validate. Use a label.

It is not correct. It is not accessible. You see it on some websites because some developers are just lazy. When I am hiring developers, this is one of the first things I check for in candidates work. Forms are nasty, but take the time and learn to do them properly

Answer (score -7):

#### No, its not

`<div>` tags are always abused to create a web layout. Its symbolic purpose is to divide a section/portion in the page so that separate style can be added or applied to it. <sup>*[[w3schools Doc]](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)*</sup> <sup>*[[W3C]](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div)*</sup>

### It highly depends on what your `some` and `another` has.

HTML5, has more logical meaning tags, instead of having plain layout tags. The `section`, `header`, `nav`, `aside` everything have their own semantic meaning to it. And are used against `<div>`

Comment: I tend to agree.  There are _many_ things you _can_ do inside html.  But because of those loose guidelines is why we find ourselves digging out of the mess of tabled web layouts with code full of hacks.  The only way the web can grow is if we continue to follow the new guidelines as they are presented to us.

Comment: Well, I need a some area on web page.  Users click on this areas and set values on form inputs.  What HTML-element fits for this case?

Comment: @demas, For the use of your defination `<select>` fits perfect if the choices are given, if not `<a>` or `<buttons>` are good.

Comment: -1 you are totaly wrong. EVERY BIG SITE use div inside a form. you gave in html 5 examples which has nothing to do with the question. show me one big site which doesnt have div within form. people here in this site throuws answers without checking and mislead other users

Comment: @demas before you ask such question - check from big sites. and view their source. it is perfectly fine doing so.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, No I am not wrong, I have clearly mentioned `it highly depends what your some and another has.` for the cases you are referring to. So chill

Comment: the way to not build something is to look at how enterprise code did it, as a rule.    if you are only using those div's to contain text, if the text applies to the form controls, use a label. if not, use a p. semantics matter. accessibility matters.