# ruby forms in div elements

Tags: ruby, forms, html, erb

I'm having an issue where the form generated with ruby isn't included inside my `#content` div, is this because the form is generated after the html is read by the browser (sorry if I sound like a moron on this)

-- edit update - view source --

The code below generates with the email box and submit button outside of the content box

```
<div id="content">
<!-- text here -->
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/password_resets" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="afmtpSAc93w1uMcnouhY9XmbVTM7fE1VNFvZKnp0kMs=" />
</div>
    <div class="field"> 
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@website.com" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
</form> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<% end -%>` May be this is causing the issue. Try changing it to `<% end %>`.

Comment: No, erb is server-side. It is procesed before anything is sent to the browser. What output do you get?

Comment: Are you sure it is actually outside the box *in the source*? Else it might be that you have floating elements which do not add height to #content. Anyways, please check the HTML output by doing "View Source" (rather than "Inspect Element") in your browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the question right, but in the html above the last `</form> </div>` should be  `</div> </form>`

Comment: right, but this is the original code, pre-ruby compile.

also is there a way to make this block instead of inline in comments?

`<div id="content">
<h1>Forgot your password?</h1>
<p>Happens to me all the time.</p>
<p>Enter your email address and we'll send you instructions to change your password</p>
<%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
 <div class="field"> 
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "email@website.com" %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %>
 </div>
<% end -%>
</div>`

Comment: actually it goes div content > form > div's for inputs > /divs > /form > /div content. the div's inside the form aren't rendering as part of the content div...I could give the content div a height that includes those inputs, but that's more of a bandaid than a solution

Comment: any reason for <% end -%> and not <% end %> ?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out after visiting this link
[Is it correct to use DIV inside FORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942538/is-it-correct-to-use-div-inside-form)

once I removed the div's for field and action it cleared everything up