# Separating a form into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is separate the following form into 2 columns with a vertical divider splitting the two, but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is [an image of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04AES.png).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">  
  <form class="form-large">
    <!-- THIS FORM NEEDS TO BE SPLIT IN 2 COLUMNS SUCH THAT I CAN PUT CONTENT IN BOTH -->   
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-large {
    max-width: 884px;
    padding: 15px 15px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Very similar to already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942538/is-it-correct-to-use-div-inside-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a left and a right div with `display: inline-block` and a set width:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/eGjPa/

You have asked for exact widths, so if you want to prevent wrapping just put `white-space: nowrap` on the form.  Otherwise, use percentage widths or something.

Comment: Just to add to this. Say the width of the form were 1000px, the left column was 640px and the right column was 300px. How would I create a space between those columns and add a vertical divider between them stretching to the height of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Make a pixel 1px X 2px .. and apply it has a vertical background

```
.form-large { 
    ...
    background:transparent url(1pxX2pximage.img) repeat-y scroll 0 584px;
    ...
}
```