# Is it possible to code a form over multiple divs?

Tags: forms, html, input

I'm coding an email subscription form (api's proving a nightmare on their own) and I was wondering if it is possible to write a form across divs, as per below...

```
<div id="topsubscribe_label">STAY UP TO DATE, JOIN OUR MAILING LIST: </div>     

<form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
<div id="subforminputs">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="toptextinput" value="" placeholder="you@example.com"/><br />
</div>      

<div id="topsubscribe_submit">
<input type="submit" id="topregisterButton" name="submit" class="textinput" value="Subscribe" />
</form>         
</div>
```

Will this break the form? Is there another (simple) way to do this?

Comment: You can use multiple divs within a form, but you cannot close a parent before the child is closed. What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: So long as your markup is valid, you're fine. If you're not sure, use an HTML validator: http://html5.validator.nu/

Comment: Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942538/is-it-correct-to-use-div-inside-form

Comment: please note that if you wish to define different "zones" in your form , the `fieldset` tag may be of use

Comment: When viewing @cezar's linked question, be careful to note the votes on the answers rather than just going with the one marked as "accepted."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
<div>
  <div>
  <form>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do this

```
<form>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But you cannot do this

```
<form>
  <div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Browser won't show any errors, you might have different output. Each browser handles these error diffrently.

Answer (score 2):

This is acceptable:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <div><input /><input /></div>
    <div><input /><input /></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is not:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input /><input />
</div>
<div>
    <input /><input />
  </form>
</div>
```

It may be worth noting that overlapping tags as in the 2nd example is invalid for *all* tags; not just `form` tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to group some fields, you can use `fieldset` element.