# Is it correct to use FORM to the INPUT that is inside DIV?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have been wondering about usage of HTML `<form>` tag. I needed it for my `<input>` elements that are inside `<div>` containers.

```
<form>
    <div id="container1">
        <input type="text" name="first" id="name">
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <input type="text" name="second" id="surname">
    </div>
</form>
```

Is it correct and natural to do this? would this capture all input elements inside form? If not is there any better way or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form is a block-level element in HTML. Typically, block-level elements allow both block-level and inline children.

Both div and span are valid children of form.

This link would help you to understand better

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

but You can always use [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your html.

Hope this would help. You can also read about [Box Modle](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for more understanding on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Using `div` inside `form` tag is absolutely acceptable, but you can try to use `label` tag instead of div in this case.
More information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942538/is-it-correct-to-use-div-inside-form).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, does label tag have advantages over div in this case?

Comment: It depends on your case. A label element helps user to have a focus on an input element after click on label.

Comment: W3C says: The <label> element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the <label> element, it toggles the control.

Comment: `label` should provide clear description of the element's purpose as it is being read to people with sight impairments by screen readers; if you want to have accessible website you should associate every form element with a `label`